# Proportional editing problem

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender and I have a problem that I can't solve and where the internet won't help me.
I have a column and want to make it look like it was cut. So I want that the upper vertice goes into the blue circle and that the other vertices makes a straight line to the lower vertice. I tried to use the proportional edit tool but none of the meshes  solves the problem. So is it possible to use the proportional editing but fixing a vertice and making the other vertices do a straight line between the fixe vertice and the edit one ?

[image: Image of the problem]

Answer (score 2):

Add a cube, and position it so that its lower face sits where you'd like the cylinder's vertices to be. The tip of the cylinder should be *inside* the cube.

[image: Cube]

Select the cylinder. In the *Modifier Properties* tab, on the right-hand side pannel, add a *Boolean* modifier. Make sure it's set to *Difference* and, under *object*, select the cube (be aware that there might be many cubes in your scene; make sure to select the right one).

[image: Boolean]

Your cylinder should now bear a cut as the one you described. If evertyhing seems to be in order, hit *Apply* in the boolean modifier and get rid of the cube.

[image: Cut cylinder]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your response was really helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is good, but another way while steering clear of modifiers would be knife tool. <kbd>k</kbd> to start, then <kbd>c</kbd> to lock it 45 degree angles, then <kbd>z</kbd> to cut through the whole mesh (you may wish to use hide <kbd>h</kbd> to hide parts not to be cut) then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the cut. Then just delete the top part and fill the resulting loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked perfectly well.